# Recommended libraries/howtos for using WMI with java?

Tags: windows, wmi, java

Hey Folks. I have a reasonably large commercial project (so for-pay licensing is always an option) that is moving into the windows space and I am planning on doing alot of polling with WMI. This is a Java 1.6 client app. Are there any good resources or books out there to get me started in accomplishing this in java? I feel my .NET fu is pretty strong, but I often don't know where to start to accomplish the same tasks in Java.

Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I don't know of any books specific to Java, but If I can offer some advice it would be to just start with WMI MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Also, since WMI is a COM based API, I would look into using a Java to COM bridge for accessing the API. Any one of the following should work:

- [Java2Com](http://www.java2com.com/)
- [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) - A WMI [example](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet3297.htm).
- [J-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/) - A WMI [example](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/#other_examples/WMI_Scripting_from_Java.htm).
- [J-Interop](http://www.j-interop.org/) -  A WMI [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310355/how-do-i-access-windows-event-viewer-log-data-from-java).
- Another [Java2Com](http://apollosoft.net/products/java2com/) tool

For a Java wrapper around WMI, there is the [jWMI](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/) library.

Comment: JACOB and Apollosoft links are broken. J-interop example link is not an example, it is another SO question.

Answer (score 10):

I would like to spread some word of warning regarding the jWMI: in case you do not have control over the systems where your app will run (say simple desktop application), expect issues with the antiviruses. jWMI is not a real library, but merely a utility. It creates a jwmi.vbs file on flight and simply tries to execute it with the "cmd /c" Runtime call. As you might imagine, the antiviruses are typically not happy with such behaviour and sandbox/block the file immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the caution. Our early implementation did this directly, so one more reason to avoid using a library to do the same.

Answer (score 4):

Below is an example of using [Jawin](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/) to get the system uptime using WMI.

To run the code, you will need to download [Jawin](http://jawinproject.sourceforge.net/) library and add `jawin.dll` to your eclipse project root

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws COMException {
String computerName = "";
String userName = "";
String password = "";
String namespace = "root/cimv2";

String queryProcessor = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";

DispatchPtr dispatcher = null;

try {

    ISWbemLocator locator = new ISWbemLocator(
            "WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");
    ISWbemServices wbemServices = locator.ConnectServer(computerName,
            namespace, userName, password, "", "", 0, dispatcher);
    ISWbemObjectSet wbemObjectSet = wbemServices.ExecQuery(
            queryProcessor, "WQL", 0, null);
    DispatchPtr[] results = new DispatchPtr[wbemObjectSet.getCount()];
    IUnknown unknown = wbemObjectSet.get_NewEnum();
    IEnumVariant enumVariant = (IEnumVariant) unknown
            .queryInterface(IEnumVariant.class);

    enumVariant.Next(wbemObjectSet.getCount(), results);

    for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        ISWbemObject wbemObject = (ISWbemObject) results[i]
                .queryInterface(ISWbemObject.class);

        System.out.println("Uptime: "
                + wbemObject.get("LastBootUpTime"));
    }
} catch (COMException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```