# Infromation from IIS 7.0

Tags: java, iis, coldfusion

Is there a way I can get some information from my IIS 7.0 using Java or Coldfusion?

I want to make a dash board for the sites which are there on my iis 7.0 with informations like whether it is running or not, and list all the virtual directories for every site.

Answer (score 1):

You could use WMI. WMI IIS interface is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347459%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

and then [Recommended libraries/howtos for using WMI with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610063/recommended-libraries-howtos-for-using-wmi-with-java)

Comment: I think Adobe's Web Server Configuration Tool uses CF's ability to talk to .NET.  Maybe you can find out how to use WMI using .NET and uses `<cfobject>`?  Maybe you can safe yourself from using the  "Recommended libraries" in the answer