# Java - Is it possible to programmatically determine if the Windows antivirus solution is up to date?

Tags: java, windows, antivirus

Is it possible to programmatically determine if the Windows antivirus solution is up to date within Java?

Comment: Yes, that's possible! Is it a simple task? Probably not.

Comment: Is there maybe a systems call you can make. From what I understand windows has a way of allowing other programs to get the antivirus status. I guess I'm wondering if it's possible within a Java app versus say a .net app

Comment: You might want to use WMI for that, there's [an answer on SO for C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1331918/916657). As for how to do this in Java, there's [jWMI](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/) and [several other approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4638004/916657).

Comment: A specific antivirus solution or any?

Comment: Whichever solution is installed. The same way Windows know it's up to date and other programs I've use that same status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `productUptoDate` property of the `AntiVirusProduct` WMI Class. Here you have some samples (in C# and Delphi) of use and the location(the namespace depends of the Windows version) of such class.

- [`Detect Antivirus on Windows using C#`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331887/detect-antivirus-on-windows-using-c-sharp/1331918#1331918)
- [Getting the installed Antivirus, AntiSpyware and Firewall software using Delphi and the WMI](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/02/18/getting-the-installed-antivirus-antispyware-and-firewall-software-using-delphi-and-the-wmi/)

for access th WMI service from Java you can use [`jinterop`](http://www.j-interop.org/) or [`jWMI`](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/)

Comment: Using the jWMI, i can't find exactly how to query the display name with this command : System.out.println(getWMIValue("Select * from AntivirusProduct","displayName"));

Answer (score 2):

This is a VBScript our company used to use - it uses WMI as Niklas B.'s solution does as well, so it will only work on XP SP3+. It uses the same provider as Windows Security Center (which doesn't always pick up every AV solution! However, does provide a lot of information on the AV solution.

```
Set objSWbemServices = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\SecurityCenter")
Set colFirewall = objSWbemServices.ExecQuery("Select * From antivirusProduct",,48)
For Each objAntiVirusProduct In colFirewall
  WScript.Echo "companyName: " & objAntiVirusProduct.companyName
  WScript.Echo "displayName: " & objAntiVirusProduct.displayName
  WScript.Echo "instanceGuid: " & objAntiVirusProduct.instanceGuid
  WScript.Echo "onAccessScanningEnabled: " & objAntiVirusProduct.onAccessScanningEnabled
  WScript.Echo "productUptoDate: " & objAntiVirusProduct.productUptoDate
  WScript.Echo "versionNumber: " & objAntiVirusProduct.versionNumber
Next
```

Best of luck and happy coding!