# Get disk signatures?

Tags: java, windows, disk

Using Java, is it possible to get the so called windows "disk signature" of a drive? I know I could somehow parse the output of diskpart, but that wouldn't be such a great solution ):

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it with Java but I've worked with the [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before via Python and found to be a really pleasant way of working with Windows. The disk signature is available in the [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s Signature property.

The answer to [Recommended libraries/howtos for using WMI with java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610063/recommended-libraries-howtos-for-using-wmi-with-java) mentions a few Java to COM bridges that would allow you to tap into the api and mentions [this site](http://www.vijaykandy.com/2009/09/windows-management-instrumentation-wmi-from-java/) that looks like it gives a decent example of how to go about accessing WMI from Java.