# Get performance data from WMI

Tags: windows, wmi, windows-server-2008, wmi-query

Is there any information how I can get these values from WMI using the SQL like quires:

```
OS uptime

CPU load

RAM utilization

HDD utilization
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve such info from the accessing the performance counters classes. All is described in the MSDN documentation.

- [WMI Performance Counter Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394569%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`Monitoring Performance Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392397%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [`Obtaining Statistical Performance Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392723%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm already aware of this information. How I can this information using Java?

Comment: For Java try this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610063/recommended-libraries-howtos-for-using-wmi-with-java?