# How to intercept Windows startup event in Swing

Tags: java, windows, swing

I created a `JFrame` with a few labels. I need to display a `JOptionPane` with the message "welcome user" once. If the frame is re-opened before rebooting Windows, the `JOptionPane` should not appear, but if Windows is rebooted, the `JOptionPane` should appear again.

How am I able to detect whether the system has been rebooted, since the last time my application ran?

Comment: consider making a SSCCE (short self contained correct example)

Comment: i dont hav code yet bcoz m confused where to start

Comment: So you're looking for something like Windows.isRestarted()? Sorry, there's no such thing :)

Comment: You may be able to store something in a temporary file? What OS is this?

Comment: Is this really necessary?  If I were the user, I'd be annoyed at having to click OK on a welcome screen every day.  Unless this is some kind of forced agreement, show the welcome screen once.  If the user needs the welcome screen, have a menu option for it.

Comment: yes @GilbertLeBlanc this is the what the client is asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as @Kayaman mentioned, there isn't an `isRebooted()` method in Java... but you can make one.

Assuming you are working on Windows platforms (you would need to implement a separate version for other OSes), you could query the [system event log](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308427). With all the stuff that gets put in there I reckon it would include an event for "logged in", so all you need to do is find a way to look up the last "logged in" time and see if it has changed since the last time you checked.

Accessing the event log is a windows specific trick, and so won't be in the native java api, however there is a question on how to [access the event log from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310355/how-do-i-access-windows-event-viewer-log-data-from-java) which you could use as a base.

Answer (score 1):

Drop a BAT script in the Autostart folder of the user which creates a file in a specific location:

```
echo JUST_STARTED > C:\NAME_OF_YOUR_APP.TXT
```

In your app, check whether the file exists. If it does, delete it and display the message.